# ¿Que comillas estan mal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Chicos tengo un codigo en javascript que no me compila pues tengo varias comillas simples entre dobles y no se cuales estan mal posicionadas o si me faltan algunas aca les dejo el fragmento de código, gracias de antemano.

```
  var ret = '<div class="app-item animated fadeIn" user="' + nick + '" time="' + $.now() + '"><div class="app-item-avatar"><a class="zoom" href="' + thumb2 + '"><img src="' + thumb + '" class="img-circle" width="44" height="42"></a></div><div class="app-item-msg"><nick class="stt' + group + '" onclick="mention(\'' + nick + "');\">" + nick + "</nick>" + badge + "<time>" + hora() + "</time><p>Audio: </p><audio controls="" src="src?rec='+audio+'"></audio></div></div>";

$('#zone-boddy div[zone-id="'+to+'"]').append(ret);
```

Comment: Qué no te funciona? qué falla? cuál es el error?

Comment: para empeza todo eso empieza con ' y termina con "

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No imprime nada, es decir alguna comilla esta mal posicionada y el codigo se detiene. Este fragmento es parte de un codigo mayor de una opcion de compartir audio en un chat

Comment: solucion usa [plantillas de cadenas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe una forma más elegante que se llama "plantillas literales" o en el buen inglés "template literals", para ello veamos un simpático proceso:

Paso 1. Darle una sangría y saltos de línea para mejor visualización:

```
var ret = 
'<div class="app-item animated fadeIn" user="' + nick + '" time="' + $.now() + '">
<div class="app-item-avatar">
<a class="zoom" href="' + thumb2 + '">
<img src="' + thumb + '" class="img-circle" width="44" height="42">
</a>
</div>
<div class="app-item-msg">
<nick class="stt' + group + '" onclick="mention(\'' + nick + "');\">" + nick + "</nick>" 
+ badge + "<time>" + hora() + "</time>
<p>Audio: </p>
<audio controls="" src="src?rec='+audio+'"></audio>
</div>
</div>";
```

Paso 2. Agregar las comillas inversas al inicio y al final de ese bloque que será tu plantilla.

```
var ret = 
`'<div class="app-item animated fadeIn" user="' + nick + '" time="' + $.now() + '">
<div class="app-item-avatar">
<a class="zoom" href="' + thumb2 + '">
<img src="' + thumb + '" class="img-circle" width="44" height="42">
</a>
</div>
<div class="app-item-msg">
<nick class="stt' + group + '" onclick="mention(\'' + nick + "');\">" + nick + "</nick>" 
+ badge + "<time>" + hora() + "</time>
<p>Audio: </p>
<audio controls="" src="src?rec='+audio+'"></audio>
</div>
</div>"`;
```

Paso 3. Definir las variables donde aplicas concatenación.

```
var nick, horaActual, thumb2, thumb, group, badge, audio; //podrías usar `let` en lugar de `var`
```

Paso 4. Establecer los valores a las variables del punto 3

```
var nick, horaActual, thumb2, thumb, group, badge, audio, hora;

nick = "El username es Nick";
var horaActual = new Date().toLocaleString();
thumb2 = "algunEnlace";
thumb = "algunaImage.jpg";
group = "algunGrupoCSS";
audio = "aquiUnAudio.wav";
```

Paso 5. Eliminar las comilas simples, los signos de suma y las barras invertidas que fueron usadas para la concatenación y dar una sangría para placer visual o mejor dicho, para tener mayor facilidad de encontrar bugs.

```
var ret = 
`<div class="app-item animated fadeIn" user="${nick}" time="${horaActual}">
  <div class="app-item-avatar">
    <a class="zoom" href="${thumb2}">
      <img src="${thumb}" class="img-circle" width="44" height="42">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="app-item-msg">
    <nick class="stt ${group}" onclick="mention('${nick}')>
      ${nick}  
    </nick> 
    ${badge} 
    <time>${horaActual}</time>
    <p>Audio: </p>
    <audio controls="" src="src?rec=${audio}"></audio>
  </div>
</div>`;
```

El único detalle de este enfoque: Es inútil en Internet Explorer porque IE carece de soporte para esa característica y siendo realistas ¿Cuándo fue la última vez que tuvieron algún cliente que utilizó dicho navegador?

Lectura recomendada: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

Para ese tipo de manejo de strings te sugiero que utilices *template literals*.

Estos te permitirán tener un mejor control del string que estás construyendo y favorece la legibilidad del código para futuros cambios.

```
var a = "spanName";
var b = "Span value";
var ret = `<span name="${a}">${b}</span>`;
```

Salida:

> `"<span name="spanName">Span value</span>"`

Template literals son soportados por Firefox 34, Chrome 41, y Edge 12 y superior, pero no por Internet Explorer.

Más info [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Answer (score 0):

Este fragmento está raro. Después de concatenar la variable nick, retomas la cadena con comilla doble.

```
onclick="mention(\'' + nick + "');\">"
```